# How to predict a certain time span into the future with recurrent neural networks in Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, time-series

I have the following code for time series predictions with RNNs and I would like to know whether for the testing I predict one day in advance:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Time Series Prediction with  RNN

"""
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from tensorflow import keras


#%%  Configure parameters

epochs = 5
batch_size = 50

steps_backwards = int(1* 4 * 24)
steps_forward = int(1* 4 * 24)

split_fraction_trainingData = 0.70
split_fraction_validatinData = 0.90


#%%  "Reading the data"

dataset = pd.read_csv('C:/User1/Desktop/TestValues.csv', sep=';', header=0, low_memory=False, infer_datetime_format=True, parse_dates={'datetime':[0]}, index_col=['datetime'])

df = dataset
data = df.values
indexWithYLabelsInData = 0
data_X = data[:, 0:2]
data_Y = data[:, indexWithYLabelsInData].reshape(-1, 1)

#%%   Prepare the input data for the RNN

series_reshaped_X =  np.array([data_X[i:i + (steps_backwards+steps_forward)].copy() for i in range(len(data) - (steps_backwards+steps_forward))])
series_reshaped_Y =  np.array([data_Y[i:i + (steps_backwards+steps_forward)].copy() for i in range(len(data) - (steps_backwards+steps_forward))])


timeslot_x_train_end = int(len(series_reshaped_X)* split_fraction_trainingData)
timeslot_x_valid_end = int(len(series_reshaped_X)* split_fraction_validatinData)

X_train = series_reshaped_X[:timeslot_x_train_end, :steps_backwards] 
X_valid = series_reshaped_X[timeslot_x_train_end:timeslot_x_valid_end, :steps_backwards] 
X_test = series_reshaped_X[timeslot_x_valid_end:, :steps_backwards] 


indexWithYLabelsInSeriesReshapedY = 0
lengthOfTheYData = len(data_Y)-steps_backwards -steps_forward
Y = np.empty((lengthOfTheYData, steps_backwards, steps_forward))  
for step_ahead in range(1, steps_forward + 1):     
   Y[..., step_ahead - 1] =   series_reshaped_Y[..., step_ahead:step_ahead + steps_backwards, indexWithYLabelsInSeriesReshapedY]
 
Y_train = Y[:timeslot_x_train_end] 
Y_valid = Y[timeslot_x_train_end:timeslot_x_valid_end] 
Y_test = Y[timeslot_x_valid_end:]


#%%  Build the model and train it

model = keras.models.Sequential([
    keras.layers.SimpleRNN(90, return_sequences=True, input_shape=[None, 2]),
    keras.layers.SimpleRNN(60, return_sequences=True),
    keras.layers.TimeDistributed(keras.layers.Dense(steps_forward))
    #keras.layers.Dense(steps_forward)
])

model.compile(loss="mean_squared_error", optimizer="adam", metrics=['mean_absolute_percentage_error'])
history = model.fit(X_train, Y_train, epochs=epochs, batch_size=batch_size,
                    validation_data=(X_valid, Y_valid))


#%%    #Predict the test data
Y_pred = model.predict(X_test)

prediction_lastValues_list=[]

for i in range (0, len(Y_pred)):
  prediction_lastValues_list.append((Y_pred[i][0][steps_forward-1]))

#%% Create thw dataframe for the whole data

wholeDataFrameWithPrediciton = pd.DataFrame((X_test[:,0]))
wholeDataFrameWithPrediciton.rename(columns = {indexWithYLabelsInData:'actual'}, inplace = True)
wholeDataFrameWithPrediciton.rename(columns = {1:'Feature 1'}, inplace = True)
wholeDataFrameWithPrediciton['predictions'] = prediction_lastValues_list
wholeDataFrameWithPrediciton['difference'] = (wholeDataFrameWithPrediciton['predictions'] - wholeDataFrameWithPrediciton['actual']).abs()
wholeDataFrameWithPrediciton['difference_percentage'] = ((wholeDataFrameWithPrediciton['difference'])/(wholeDataFrameWithPrediciton['actual']))*100
```

I define `eps_forward = int(1* 4 * 24)` which is basically one full day (in 15 minutes resolution which makes 1 * 4 *24 = 96 time stamps). I predict the test data by using `Y_pred = model.predict(X_test)` and I create a list with the predicted values by using `for i in range (0, len(Y_pred)): prediction_lastValues_list.append((Y_pred[i][0][steps_forward-1]))`

As for me the input and output data of RNNs is quite confusing I am not sure whether for the test dataset I predict one day in advance meaning 96 time steps into the future. Actually what I want is to read historic data and then predict the next 96 time steps based on the historic 96 time steps. Can anyone of you tell me whether I am doing this by using this code or not?

Here I have a link to some test data that I just created randomly. Do not care about the actual values but just on the structure of the prediction: [Download Test Data](https://filetransfer.io/data-package/h2JcE6tq#link)

Am I forecasting 96 steps in advance with the given code (my code is based on a tutorial that can be found here [Tutorial RNN for electricity price prediction](https://towardsdatascience.com/recurrent-neural-networks-for-electricity-price-prediction-a26f8411ea44))?

**Reminder**: Can anyone tell me something about my question? Or do you need further information? If so, please tell me.
I'll highly appreciate your comments and will be quite thankful for your help. I will also award a bounty for a useful answer.

Comment: What exactly do you want to find out?

Comment: Thanks AloneTogether for your comment. I would like to find out whether I am  forecasting 96 steps in advance with the given code for every time slot.

Comment: Can you explain how your training data is created? What exactly are you trying to do? I know you posted your code but I am not sure why exactly you are preprocessing your data the way you are doing it

Comment: Thanks AloneTogether for your comment. Actually I just took a tutorial about electricity price prediction as a basis for my code (https://towardsdatascience.com/recurrent-neural-networks-for-electricity-price-prediction-a26f8411ea44) and adjusted it accordingly. As far as I understand the inputdata of a RNN (or LSTM) has to have a certain shape (that has been very difficult for me to understand). The training data is transformed in my code such that it has this certain shape for RNNs. And as always you have a training, validation and test set.

Comment: @AloneTogether: Do you need any further information?

Comment: @AloneTogether: Cool. I really appreciate your effort.

Comment: @AloneTogether: If I remeber correctly, you intended to write an answer. Are you still planning to do that or not? I'll appreciate any further comment from you.

Comment: I was planning to but I figured the other answer already helped you.

Comment: @AloneTogether: Thanks for your comment. Actually the other answer does not really help me a lot (but I did not downvote it; that was someone else) because of 2 reasons. First of all it does not answer my core question whether I am forecasting 96 steps in advance with the given code. Moreover I have some problems understanding the answer that I posted in comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if your goal is to predict the next 96 steps given 96 steps in the past, I think you are over-complicating it with your current model. Why not start off with something simple like this:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler

np.random.seed(42)
tf.random.set_seed(42)

df = pd.read_csv('TestValues.csv', sep=';', header=0, low_memory=False, infer_datetime_format=True, parse_dates={'datetime':[0]}, index_col=['datetime'])
df = df.drop('value', 1)
steps = 96
scaler = MinMaxScaler()
data = scaler.fit_transform(df.values)
series_reshaped =  np.array([data[i:i + (steps+steps)].copy() for i in range(len(data) - (steps + steps))])

x_train_index = int(len(series_reshaped)* .80)
x_valid_index = int(len(series_reshaped)* .10)
x_test_index = x_train_index + x_valid_index

X_train = series_reshaped[:x_train_index, :steps] 
X_valid = series_reshaped[x_train_index: x_test_index, :steps] 
X_test = series_reshaped[x_test_index:, :steps] 

Y_train = series_reshaped[:x_train_index, steps:] 
Y_valid = series_reshaped[x_train_index: x_test_index, steps:] 
Y_test = series_reshaped[x_test_index:, steps:]

model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.SimpleRNN(96, return_sequences=True, input_shape=(None, 1)),
    tf.keras.layers.TimeDistributed(tf.keras.layers.Dense(1))
])

model.compile(loss='mae', optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(0.001))
history = model.fit(X_train, Y_train, epochs=20,
                    validation_data=(X_valid, Y_valid))
```

You simply split your data into the 96 steps for training and 96 steps forward as your "labels". After training just make your predictions with your test data:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

Y_pred = model.predict(X_test)
prediction_list = []

for i in range (0, len(Y_pred)):
  prediction_list.append(Y_pred[i][0])

prediction_df = pd.DataFrame((Y_test[:, 0]))
prediction_df.rename(columns = {0:'actual'}, inplace = True)
prediction_df['predictions'] = prediction_list
prediction_df['difference'] = (prediction_df['predictions'] - prediction_df['actual']).abs()
prediction_df['difference_percentage'] = ((prediction_df['difference'])/(prediction_df['actual']))*100

print(prediction_df)
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize = (24,12))
ax.set_title('Temperatures across time', fontsize=20)
ax.set_xlabel('Timesteps', fontsize=20)
ax.tick_params(axis='both', which='major', labelsize=20)
ax.set_ylabel('Temperature', fontsize=20)
plt1 = ax.plot(prediction_df['predictions'][steps:], color = 'g', label='predictions')
plt2 = ax.plot(prediction_df['actual'][steps:], color = 'r', label='actual')
ax.legend(loc='upper left', prop={'size': 20})
```

```
       actual   predictions       difference difference_percentage
0    0.540650  [0.52996427]    [0.010686159]           [1.9765377]
1    0.550813   [0.5463712]   [0.0044417977]           [0.8064075]
2    0.544715  [0.54527795]  [0.00056248903]           [0.1032629]
3    0.543360   [0.5469178]    [0.003557384]          [0.65470064]
4    0.547425   [0.5332471]    [0.014178336]            [2.590003]
..        ...           ...              ...                   ...
977  0.410569    [0.440537]    [0.029967904]           [7.2991133]
978  0.395664  [0.44218686]    [0.046522915]           [11.758189]
979  0.414634    [0.448785]     [0.03415087]            [8.236386]
980  0.414634  [0.43778685]    [0.023152709]           [5.5838885]
981  0.409214  [0.45098385]    [0.041769773]           [10.207315]
```

[image]

Note that this model can be improved in a lot of ways, but I want you to understand the basics, which is why I tried to make it as simple as possible. After you have understood this approach, you can try an autoregressive approach as mentioned by elbe. Also note that I have not de-normalised your data, which is why you get very low values.

Comment: Thanks a lot AloneTogether for your answer and effort. I really appreciate it. Could you figure out what exactly I was predicting with my code (I took it from a tutorial and if it is true what you assume that the code does not predict 96 time steps in advance, and I believe you, the tutorial seems to be wrong). I had a look at your code and honestly I do not see any major changes. What did you do different?

Comment: Look at how I am creating your data. It does not mean that the tutorial is wrong, you might just have another use case. There is, however, something weird in the tutorial. The user uses `X_test` to make predictions and then later uses `X_test` as his actual values again instead of his `Y_test`. Maybe a typo. It really does not matter. Start off small, understand what is happening in your model, and then move on.

Comment: Thanks for your comment AloneTogether. Your `series_reshaped` is a little bit different (but I don't understand it at all and I also didn't understand this in the tutorial). So in your code are you predicting 96 steps in the future? How can one be sure about that? You are using the same code for the evaluation `for i in range (0, len(Y_pred)):
  prediction_list.append(Y_pred[i][0])` as in the tutorial. Further, you are only using 1 feature. How can I adjust the code to use more features? And how can I adjust the windows for predictions. E.g. using the last 90 time steps to predict the next 10

Comment: Let us look at an example that I am using: `X_train `  and `Y_test `. As  you know (and according to the tutorial) you created a time dimension by converting `data` with the shape (10000, 1) to `series_reshaped` with the shape (9808, 192, 1). Now after figuring out how many samples I want to use for training, I split the data into `X_train` which contains the first 96 steps and `Y_train` which contains the last 96 steps for each sample. The goal of the model is therefore to predict the 96 steps based on the first 96 steps.

Comment: The same applies to `X_valid ` and `Y_valid` as well as  `X_test` and `Y_test`

Comment: But that is also done in my code as far as I see it.

Answer (score 0):

First, I suggest you read [Tensorflow's tutorial on time series forecasting](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/structured_data/time_series).
I played around a bit with your code and the data provided.
The first important thing is that only the temperature column contains information.
In the code below, I prepare the data so that X over a time window of 96 samples/steps and the next step is in Y. X is of dimension (n_samples, 96, 1) and Y of dimension (n_samples, ), I use only steps_backwards points for the past (and discarded the future for simplicity, without affecting the generality)
I have tried different models (a simple Fully Connected or RNN + FC, etc.).
I'm doing mean pooling (with the functional API rather than the sequential model definition approach) so that I have a single predicted value at the end.

```
X_train = series_reshaped_X[:timeslot_x_train_end, :steps_backwards, 1][:, :, np.newaxis] 
X_valid = series_reshaped_X[timeslot_x_train_end:timeslot_x_valid_end, :steps_backwards, 1][:, :, np.newaxis]  
X_test = series_reshaped_X[timeslot_x_valid_end:, :steps_backwards, 1][:, :, np.newaxis]  

Y_train = series_reshaped_X[:timeslot_x_train_end, steps_backwards, 1]
Y_valid = series_reshaped_X[timeslot_x_train_end:timeslot_x_valid_end, steps_backwards, 1]
Y_test = series_reshaped_X[timeslot_x_valid_end:, steps_backwards, 1]
# define the model
input = tf.keras.Input(shape=(96, 1))
x = input
x = keras.layers.SimpleRNN(10, return_sequences=False, input_shape=[96, 1])(x)
x = keras.layers.Dense(5)(x)
x = tf.reduce_mean(x, axis=1)
model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=input, outputs=x)

model.compile(loss="mean_squared_error", optimizer="adam", metrics=['mae'])
```

with `return_sequences=False`, the RNN outputs only the last predicted value.

Model:

```
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
input_5 (InputLayer)         [(None, 96, 1)]           0         
_________________________________________________________________
simple_rnn_27 (SimpleRNN)    (None, 10)                120       
_________________________________________________________________
dense_21 (Dense)             (None, 5)                 55        
_________________________________________________________________
tf.math.reduce_mean_3 (TFOpL (None,)                   0         
=================================================================
Total params: 175
Trainable params: 175
Non-trainable params: 0
```

If you set `return_sequences=True`, the entire output sequence is outputed, but the prediction time step is still one in the RNN. It is explained [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/structured_data/time_series#recurrent_neural_network).
One way to predict more steps is to do an autoregressive approach i.e. concatenating the n-1 previous data and the predicted value to get the next value. Another (better) way is to consider that the RNN capture the time dependency in the input, so another possible model could be, if we consider that the input and the output data are of same shape:

```
input = tf.keras.Input(shape=(96, 1))
x = input
x = keras.layers.SimpleRNN(10, return_sequences=True, input_shape=[96, 1])(x)
x = keras.layers.Dense(1)(x)
model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=input, outputs=x)

model.compile(loss="mean_squared_error", optimizer="adam", metrics=['mae'])

_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
input_7 (InputLayer)         [(None, 96, 1)]           0         
_________________________________________________________________
simple_rnn_29 (SimpleRNN)    (None, 96, 10)            120       
_________________________________________________________________
dense_23 (Dense)             (None, 96, 1)             11        
=================================================================
Total params: 131
Trainable params: 131
Non-trainable params: 0
```

In a way, you can think of the RNN as being able to capture the temporal dependencies in the sequence. It can be combined with other layers to give a better predictor (e.g. the dense layer as you did or stacked RNNs etc).

Note that the number of parameters in the model summary gives you an idea of the ability of the network to learn complex relationships between inputs and outputs (and over fitting problem if the number of parameters is too high).

Comment: Thanks elbe for your informative answer. I have question on your answer and on my own code. 1) Did you have a look at my code and can you tell me whether I am predicting 96 steps into the future? And am I summarizing the correct values for a prediction of 96 steps in the future of the test data by using the loop `for i in range (0, len(Y_pred)):
  prediction_lastValues_list.append((Y_pred[i][0][steps_forward-1]))`

Comment: Now question to your approach : 2)Actually with my real data I have more columns that could provide information. How can I include them with your code? Because I do not see any variable for specifying the number of columns used from the dataframe. 3) In your second model you assume that "input and the output data are of same shape". But as far as I understand in RNN this is most of not the case because the input data might contain more features while the output data is (in my case and often) only 1 feature. So you would have to adjust the shape of your input data.